# Do geodesics in SL2R map to geodesics in the hyperbolic plane?

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, 3-manifolds

I am looking for a reference/proof/disproof of the following statement.

Equip the Lie group $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ with the left-invariant Riemannian metric, whichis given on the Lie algebra by $\langle A,B\rangle_e :=tr(AB^*)$. Let $pr:SL_2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow SL_2(\mathbb{R})/SO_2(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{H}^2$ be the canonical projection.

Is is true that $pr\circ \gamma$ is a (constant speed) geodesic in $\mathbb{H}^2$ for any geodesic $\gamma$ in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$?

The speed might even be $0$. Another similar example, where geodesics map to constant speed geodesics would just be the orthogonal projection $\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$.

Comment: Geodesics that point in the direction of the SO(2) subgroup cannot map to geodesics. I believe that these map to the constant path. If so, do you allow the constant path as a geodesic?

Comment: Tanks, Yes I would allow those. I will clarify my question now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly horizontal geodesics (perpendicular to the isotropy subgroup of the point in hyperbolic space) project to geodesics. Others do not, they give rise to more general curves
(called ballistic curves [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/orbits.pdf)).

## Edit (twice)

To be specific, my remark applies to the situation that $pr:SL_2(\mathbb R)\to \mathbb H^2$
(given by acting on $i\in \mathbb H^2$)
is a Riemannian submersion. Since we have a left action on $\mathbb H^2$, a suitable right invariant metric on $SL_2$ would furnish this. In such a situation one has: a geodesic in $SL_2$ which is perpendicular to the fibers of $pr$ at one point, is perpendicular everywhere and it projects to a geodesic on $\mathbb H^2$.

You look at a left invariant metric, but one which is given by an $SO_2$-invariant inner product on the Lie algebra. Inversion on $SL_2$ is an isometry from right to left invariant metric fixing the isotropy $SO_2$ of $i\in \mathbb H^2$. The right action of $SO_2$ on $SL_2$ is thus by isometries for the left invariant metric you use.

In this case, let me describe the geodesic equation on $SL_2$ (which differs just by a sign from the better known right invariant case)
A smooth curve $t \mapsto g(t)\in SL_2$ is a geodesic iff
$$a(t) = g(t)^{-1}.g'(t) \in \mathfrak{sl}_2$$ 
satisfies 
$$\partial_t a(t) =  ad^\bot_{a(t)}a(t)$$
where the adjoint $ad_X^\bot:\mathfrak{sl}_2\to \mathfrak{sl}_2$ is with respect to the inner product $\langle\quad,\quad\rangle_e$ so that 
$\langle ad_X^\bot Y,Z\rangle_e = \langle Y,[X,Z]\rangle_e$.

Moreover, for $X\in \mathfrak{so}_2$, the left invariant vector field $L_X$ on $SL_2$ is the infinitesimal generator for the right $SO_2$ action; the momentum mapping (for the lifted action) implies that $\langle X, a(t)=g(t)^{-1}.g'(t)\rangle_e$ is constant in $t$ for each geodesic $g(t)$ on $SL_2$. If the constant is 0 you get horizontal geodesics, and going down to $\mathbb H^2$ is at the same time the Riemannian orbit space and symplectic reduction.
If the constant is not 0, you get a conservation law for ballistic curves.

Comment: Can ballistic curves be reparameterized to become geodesics?  (Perhaps allowing variable speed?)

Comment: No they cannot, in general.

Comment: @Sam : look at the example of $S^1\times S^1=\mathbb{C}^*$ acting on $\mathbb{R^4}=\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: I am a bit confused. In my example, $\mathbb{H}^2$ is already the quotient and there is no isotropy. I could not find that specific example in the paper and for certain other examples, like $\mathbb{R}$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by translation, every geodesic maps to a (constant speed) geodesic and not only the ones that are perpendicular to the tangent space of the orbit $T_xGx\subset T_xM$.

Answer (score 2):

This is studied in the more general context of the unit tangent bundle in P. T. Nagy's [1977 paper.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5188175/nagyrev.pdf) He shows that the geodesics have constant geodesic curvature in this setting. The most general version is discussed in a later paper

```
@article {MR2027641,
    AUTHOR = {Berndt, J. and Boeckx, E. and Nagy, P. T. and Vanhecke, L.},
     TITLE = {Geodesics on the unit tangent bundle},
   JOURNAL = {Proc. Roy. Soc. Edinburgh Sect. A},
  FJOURNAL = {Proceedings of the Royal Society of Edinburgh. Section A.
              Mathematics},
    VOLUME = {133},
      YEAR = {2003},
    NUMBER = {6},
     PAGES = {1209--1229},
      ISSN = {0308-2105},
     CODEN = {PEAMDU},
   MRCLASS = {53C22 (53C25 53C35)},
 MRNUMBER = {2027641 (2004k:53054)},
 MRREVIEWER = {Andrea Spiro},
       DOI = {10.1017/S0308210500002882},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0308210500002882},
}
```